# Uncaught ReferenceError: moduleFor is not defined

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-cli, ember-testing

Ember-cli quint -> An Integration test: global failure (1, 0, 1)Rerun

Comment: import { test, moduleFor } from 'ember-qunit';